# Test NestJS Service against Actual Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to be able to test my Nest service against an actual database. I understand that most unit tests should use a mock object, but it also, at times, makes sense to test against the database itself.

I have searched through SO and the GH issues for Nest, and am starting to reach the transitive closure of all answers. :-)

I am trying to work from https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/363#issuecomment-360105413. Following is my Unit test, which uses a custom provider to pass the repository to my service class.

```js
describe("DepartmentService", () => {
  const token = getRepositoryToken(Department);
  let service: DepartmentService;
  let repo: Repository<Department>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        DepartmentService,
        {
          provide: token,
          useClass: Repository
        }
      ]
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<DepartmentService>(DepartmentService);
    repo = module.get(token);
  });
```

Everything compiles properly, TypeScript seems happy. However, when I try to execute `create` or `save` on **my** `Repository` instance, the underlying `Repository` appears to be undefined. Here's the stack backtrace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

  at Repository.Object.<anonymous>.Repository.create (repository/Repository.ts:99:29)
  at DepartmentService.<anonymous> (relational/department/department.service.ts:46:53)
  at relational/department/department.service.ts:19:71
  at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (relational/department/department.service.ts:15:12)
  at DepartmentService.addDepartment (relational/department/department.service.ts:56:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (relational/department/test/department.service.spec.ts:46:35)
  at relational/department/test/department.service.spec.ts:7:71
```

It appears that the `EntityManager` instance with the TypeORM `Repository` class is not being initialized; it is the `undefined` reference that this backtrace is complaining about.

How do I get the `Repository` and `EntityManager` to initialize properly?

thanks,
tom.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To initialize typeorm properly, you should just be able to import the `TypeOrmModule` in your test:

```
Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
   TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'mysql',
        // ...
   }),
   TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Department])
  ]
```

Comment: That is a huge step in the right direction! It appears that this causes a new database connection to be created each time the code runs. Is that correct? If so, is the right way to close the connection to run `module.close()`?
Do you recommend setting up the module in a `beforeAll` or a `beforeEach`?

Comment: Yep, it's important that you close the connection. Otherwise your test will not exit and you have to force close jest. beforeAll/afterAll sound reasonable, you can also pass `KEEP_CONNECTION_ALIVE: true` to typeorm to reuse the connection.

Comment: It seems not working with a custom repository. Any ideas @KimKern?

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim I'd assume you have to set up your test the same way you set up your database in the real application (i.e. imports). If you need more support, better open a new question so that you can post your setup (app + test that doesn't work)

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim in my case the `forFeature` included the custom repositories. As Kime said, use the same tht you uses in your module. In my case: `imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(TypeOrmConfig), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository, MessageRepository])],`

Answer (score 13):

I prefer not using `@nestjs/testing` for the sake of simplicity.

First of all, create a reusable helper:

```js
/* src/utils/testing-helpers/createMemDB.js */
import { createConnection, EntitySchema } from 'typeorm'
type Entity = Function | string | EntitySchema<any>

export async function createMemDB(entities: Entity[]) {
  return createConnection({
    // name, // let TypeORM manage the connections
    type: 'sqlite',
    database: ':memory:',
    entities,
    dropSchema: true,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
  })
}
```

Then, write test:

```
/* src/user/user.service.spec.ts */
import { Connection, Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { createMemDB } from '../utils/testing-helpers/createMemDB'
import UserService from './user.service'
import User from './user.entity'

describe('User Service', () => {
  let db: Connection
  let userService: UserService
  let userRepository: Repository<User>

  beforeAll(async () => {
    db = await createMemDB([User])
    userRepository = await db.getRepository(User)
    userService = new UserService(userRepository) // <--- manually inject
  })
  afterAll(() => db.close())

  it('should create a new user', async () => {
    const username = 'HelloWorld'
    const password = 'password'

    const newUser = await userService.createUser({ username, password })
    expect(newUser.id).toBeDefined()

    const newUserInDB = await userRepository.findOne(newUser.id)
    expect(newUserInDB.username).toBe(username)
  })
})
```

Refer to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1267#issuecomment-483775861

Comment: Can you add how `user.service` is defined?

Answer (score 12):

Here's an update to the test that employs Kim Kern's suggestion.

```js
describe("DepartmentService", () => {
  let service: DepartmentService;
  let repo: Repository<Department>;
  let module: TestingModule;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Department])
      ],
      providers: [DepartmentService]
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<DepartmentService>(DepartmentService);
    repo = module.get<Repository<Department>>(getRepositoryToken(Department));
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    module.close();
  });

  it("should be defined", () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a test orm configuration

```js
// ../test/db.ts
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm';

type Entity = Function | string | EntitySchema<any>;

export const createTestConfiguration = (
  entities: Entity[],
): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: ':memory:',
  entities,
  dropSchema: true,
  synchronize: true,
  logging: false,
});
```

which I then utilize when setting up the tests

```js
// books.service.test.ts
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HttpModule, HttpService } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { BooksService } from './books.service';
import { Book } from './book.entity';
import { createTestConfiguration } from '../../test/db';

describe('BooksService', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let service: BooksService;
  let httpService: HttpService;
  let repository: Repository<Book>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(createTestConfiguration([Book])),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Book]),
      ],
      providers: [BooksService],
    }).compile();

    httpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
    service = module.get<BooksService>(BooksService);
    repository = module.get<Repository<Book>>(getRepositoryToken(Book));
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    module.close();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
```

This allows to query the repository after the tests and ensure that the correct data was inserted.

Comment: Is this working for e2e testing, I mean when I use superset, and call the endpoint. Does this work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I usually import `AppModule` for database connection, and finally after tests are executed I close the connection:

```
  let service: SampleService;
  let connection: Connection;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([SampleEntity])],
      providers: [SampleService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<SampleService>(SampleService);
    connection = await module.get(getConnectionToken());
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used existing AppModule for testing:

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';

import { AppModule } from '../../../app.module';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

describe('AuthService', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;
    let service: AuthService;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
        service = app.get(AuthService);
    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await app.close();
    });

    it('AuthService should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe('login', () => {
        it('should login user', async () => {
            const user = await service.login({ email: 'xxxzei@mail.ru', password: '12345678' });

            expect(user.id).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

Also to add env variables in your configuration file or AppModule:

```
import { config as testConfig } from 'dotenv';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    testConfig({ path: resolve('./.env') });
}
```